# Block not found using Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, m2epro

I gatting error

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Ess_M2ePro_Controller_Adminhtml_BaseController::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, called in /var/www/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/controllers/Adminhtml/SupportController.php on line 72 and defined in /var/www/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Controller/Adminhtml/BaseController.php on line 148
```

When click on sub menu in Admin panel.

Following **app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\Block\Adminhtml\Support.php** file.

```
class Ess_M2ePro_Block_Adminhtml_Support extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    private $referrer = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('supportContainer');
        $this->_blockGroup = 'M2ePro';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml';
        $this->_mode = 'support';
        $this->referrer = $this->getRequest()->getParam('referrer');

     }
}
```

Following **app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\etc\config.xml** file.

```
<blocks>
    <M2ePro>
        <class>Ess_M2ePro_Block</class>
    </M2ePro>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <page_menu>Ess_M2ePro_Block_Adminhtml_Magento_Menu</page_menu>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
 </blocks>
```

Following **app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/controllers/Adminhtml/SupportController.php** file.

```
class Ess_M2ePro_Adminhtml_SupportController extends Ess_M2ePro_Controller_Adminhtml_BaseController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction();

        $referrer = $this->getRequest()->getParam('referrer');

        if ($referrer == Ess_M2ePro_Helper_Component_Ebay::NICK) {

            $this->setPageHelpLink(Ess_M2ePro_Helper_View_Ebay::NICK);

        } elseif ($referrer == Ess_M2ePro_Helper_View_Common::NICK) {

            $components = Mage::helper('M2ePro/View_Common_Component')->getActiveComponents();
            if (count($components) == 1) {
                $this->setPageHelpLink(array_shift($components));
            }
        }

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml/support'))
             ->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I tried to google but still did not get proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is the call to `createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml/support')` does not actually return a block.

This could be for a few different reasons the main ones being:

1. The actual file is missing,
2. The definition of blocks `M2ePro` is missing,
3. The module itself is missing,

The easiest one to check would be the module. If the M2ePro module is there then have a look in the config.xml file for the node `<blocks>` if this node is not `M2ePro` then update your code to include the correct node. Finally if this file is missing then re-download the extension and install the missing files.

Comment: I already check all this thing. Please clarify what to do for this in given code ?

Comment: get xdebug installed and step through the create block function. See when it fails :)

Comment: try `createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml_support')` (`_` instead of `/` for path separator after the module alias)

Comment: @Brice I already try `createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml_support')` but not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'M2ePro/adminhtml/support' please use 'M2ePro/adminhtml_support' change the "/" with "_"

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: typo of `'M2ePro/adminhtml/support'` should *probably* be `'M2ePro/adminhtml_support'`**.

David states that

> the call to `createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml/support')` does not actually return a block

and he is correct.

The reason why is that the following chain of calls is triggered by `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml/support')`:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Layout::createBlock('M2ePro/adminhtml/support')
Mage_Core_Model_Layout::_getBlockInstance('M2ePro/adminhtml/support')
Mage_Core_Model_Config::getBlockClassName('M2ePro/adminhtml/support')
Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName('block', 'M2ePro/adminhtml/support')
```

Inside `getGroupedClassName()` the string `M2ePro/adminhtml/support` is explode()d on the `/`, but only the first two array values (`M2ePro` and `adminhtml`) are used. `M2ePro` is correctly resolved according to configuration, but the `$class` bit is just `adminhtml` rather than `adminhtml_support`, which I'm assuming was the intention.

Comment: how the heck did I miss that :(